# Proper way to constantly check for emails

Tags: python, email, python-requests, gmail

So I have a simple piece of python code that checks a gmail account for messages:

```
import poplib
from email import parser

pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_conn.user('username')
pop_conn.pass_('password')
#Get messages from server:
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
# Concat message pieces:
messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
#Parse message intom an email object:
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
for message in messages:
    print message['subject']
pop_conn.quit()
```

Is there a best practice for basically continuously checking for messages. My initial thought was to start the code in a thread, and only authenticate once, but constantly check for messages on an interval.

Is that bad practice? I don't want to be banned by gmail for submitting too many requests.. any ideas?

Comment: whenever you're doing automated web parsing you should do your homework wrt the API limitations. most do have a threshold above which they'll refuse to serve.  idk specifically about Gmail, but I'd pose a related question to you: what interval would be satisfactorily "continuous"? do you really need to poll a gmail account once a second? that's 86,400 times per day and almost certainly above reasonable use for most API. reducing frequency to every 10 seconds is a 10x reduction to 8,640. one a minute is 1,440 and still seems like way more than you'd have practical applications for.

Comment: here's your answer on specific limits https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota